# Why there are borders appearing in a element with mix-blend-mode property?

Tags: css, sass

I am trying to fit a div inside a shape using mix-blend-mode:screen. Although on large screen it looks good when I use chrome reponsive tool on some screens are shown [borders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oG8OF.png) like this is there a way to remove these borders?

Here is my code

```
 .banner-img {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1000px;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    margin-left: -75px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    background-color: rgba(51,51,51,0.8);
    background-blend-mode: overlay;
  
    &::before{
      content: "";
       position: absolute;
       height: 100%;
       top: 0;
       left: 0;
       width: 100%;
       background-image: url('../../../Assets/mask.jpg');
       background-size: 100% 100%;
       border: none;
       mix-blend-mode: screen;
 
    }

 <div className={`banner-content ${props.styles}`}>
      <div className="banner-img" style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${props.img})` }}>
        <div className="content">{<props.content />}</div>
      </div>
      <div className="content">{props.children}</div>
    </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/d5rw3zkg/8/

Comment: Would you be able to put up a snippet with the image and the mask?

Comment: @AHaworth I put it in jsfiddle, although I can't see the border there what could be possible?
https://jsfiddle.net/d5rw3zkg/8/

Comment: I don’t really know, but I’ve seen problems where images don’t quite line up, could be the arithmetic needed when say a CSS pixel is multiple device pixels and some sort of get ‘left behind’, but I’m guessing. Will have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: the original 'fix' in this answer hid the border but altered the shape. @Alfred found that changing the height to calc(100% + 1px) rather than 101% fixed the problem - both hiding the border and keeping the correct shape.

Here's the original answer and the surmise as to the reason:

This is not a full answer to the question as I cannot reproduce the problem on any of the devices I have. But I have seen similar problems before where somehow there isn't an exact overlap of two images. This is possibly because of the mismatch between CSS and actual device pixels (which can be several pixels to make up one CSS pixel) but this is just a surmise.

Could you try this experiment? On a device where you can see the problem, also run it with just one setting changed in the SCSS. This is to see whether we can get the mask to stretch just beyond the underlying image so there is no chance of a sliver being left behind.

```
&::before{
  content: "";
   position: absolute;
   height: 100%;/**CHANGE TO 101% (original answer) now calc(100% + 1px) **/
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   background-image: url('../../../Assets/mask.jpg');
   background-size: 100% 100%;
   border: none;
   mix-blend-mode: screen;
 
}
```

Comment: adding height 101% hides the border but makes the shape lose it form, instead of rounded  it becomes square

Comment: making it calc(100% + 1px) solves the issue by both hiding the border and keeping the original shape, thanks a lot

Comment: Thanks, I should have thought of that. Interesting, may help in the other situations I’ve seen.